# GCP VueJS API URL resolving to base url not api url

Tags: vue.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, vuejs2

I'm using Google App Engine to host a VueJS App, and I'm trying to get my app to talk to my backend API.

I'm using an ENV Variable to declare the path to my API, however when the request is placed in GCP the url defaults to `https://example.com/undefined/api/resource` when it should be `https://api.example.com/api/resource` and also not have `undefined`.

As i'm getting the `undefined` error i suspect App Engine is not able to supply the `VUE_APP_API_URL` to the front end.

**How do I get my VueJS app to find and use the env variable in app engine and use the correct api url?**

Front end URL is like `example.com`

API URL is like `api.example.com`

Accessing the variable with `process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL`

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: nodejs10

env_variables:
  VUE_APP_API_URL: "https://api.example.com"

handlers:
  - url: /(.*\..+)$
    static_files: dist/\1
    upload: dist/(.*\..+)$
  - url: /.*
    static_files: dist/index.html
    upload: dist/index.html
```

Comment: Show the code of how you are trying to access the variable in VueJS

Comment: @NoCommandLine - Updated the question thanks. Using `process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL`

Comment: My experience has been that on Mac, ```process.env``` returns empty values for a slew of variables but on Windows, it returns the values. I don't know why and it is possible I'm missing something. Like you, it caused me a lot of headache when I was building https://nocommandline.com . My work-around is to explicitly set a default value for my environment variables i.e. I check if the value is null and if it is, I explicitly assign a value. To be clear, I don't have this problem for all of the env variables. For example, process.env.NODE_ENV returns values but PATH, etc are all null